# php mongodb find syntax issue

Tags: php, mongodb, find

I am trying to find the correct syntax for the find command. I have been using the following syntax for a while and it works.

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost");
$dbs = $client ->dbX->main; 
$ result = $dbs -> find ([]);
foreach($result as $main_entry) {
}
```

But when I try to modify the find() to only get the records where client is ABC, I get syntax errors. Unexpected {, expecting ]. I tried many variations but I cannot seem to find the correct syntax to make it work.

```
$ result = $dbs -> find ([ { "client" : "ABC" } ]);
```

Can someone please tell me what the correct syntax of brackets is so I can get this seemingly simple find to work? Thank you.

Comment: Drop the braces, it most likely has to be an associated array. See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-find/#phpmethod.MongoDB\Collection::find

Answer (score 0):

Basic find in php:

```
 $result = $dbs->find(array('client' => 'ABC'));
```